# why could be my mock of dynamodb scanCommand with aws-sdk-client-mock is returning undefined?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, amazon-dynamodb, mocha.js, sinon-chai

I'm doing a function which scan a table and the I use this function inside other in order to execute an elimination of data. When I do the unit test and I try to mock the scanCommand, it always send me undefined values as resolves doesn't return the data I mocked. It's nodejs with mocha-sinon project.
My code is similar to this:
repository.ts

```
public async scanData(
        length: number,
        tableName: string,
        attributesToGet: string[],
        client: DynamoDBClient
    ): Promise<ScanCommandOutput> {
        const dynamoDBDDocClientOrigin = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
 
        const inputScan: ScanCommandInput = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Select: 'SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
            Limit: length,
            ProjectionExpression: `${attributesToGet[POSITION_TYP_DOC]},${attributesToGet[POSITION_NUM_DOC]}`,
        };
        const scanCommand = new ScanCommand(inputScan);
 
        return dynamoDBDDocClientOrigin.send(scanCommand);
    }
```

The function which uses inside the other:

```
public async deleteData(
        tableName: string,
        attributesKeys: string[],
        client: DynamoDBClient
    ): Promise<IResponseDelete | IResponseErrorCopyOrDelete> {
        const repository = new DynamoDBRepositoryCollections();
        const dynamoDBDDocClientOrigin = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
 
        const resultDescribeTable = await repository.getDescribeTable(tableName, client);
 
        if (resultDescribeTable.Table?.ItemCount) {
            const contador = resultDescribeTable.Table?.ItemCount;
 
            try {
                for (let i = contador; i > 0; i -= 25) {
                    let dataToDelete = await repository.scanDataByLength(
                        25,
                        tableName,
                        attributesKeys,
                        client
                    );
 
        
 
                    const inputToDelete = await repository.batchDeleteInputObjectGenerator(
                        dataToDelete,
                        25,
                        tableName
                    );
 
                    const command = new BatchWriteItemCommand(inputToDelete);
                    if (dataToDelete.ScannedCount !== 0) {
                        await dynamoDBDDocClientOrigin.send(command);
                    }
                }
                return this.copyAndDeleteResponseMapper.mapResponseDelete(contador);
            } catch (e: any) {
                return this.mapper.mapError(e, 'Eliminado');
            }
        } else {
            return this.mapper.mapError('Error por contador', 'Eliminado');
        }
    }
```

My test:

```
it('it should delete items when scanCommand is returning data in success way', async () => {
            const dynamodbClientDelete = new DynamoDBClient({});
            const ddbMockDelete = mockClient(dynamodbClienteDelete);

            ddbMockDelete
                .on(DescribeTableCommand)
                .resolves(mockDescribeTable)
                    .on(ScanCommand).resolves(dataScannedMock) //Here resolves undefined
                .on(BatchWriteItemCommand).resolves(mockBatchWrite);

            const result = await repository.deleteData(
                'TableName',
                [attribute1, atributte2],
                dynamodbClientDelete
            );

            expect(result.status).to.be.equal(200)
        });
```

I tried manage the scan command with new stub and also configure the function with the responsibility of scanning also as a stub but in any cases always I received an undefined return. Thanks in advance for some advices.